# how to format a json file?

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I am new to JSON and I am wondering how i could format my JSON file so I will be able to render it in a barchart.

I've got the following PHP code:

```
<?php

$search_value=$_POST["search"];
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','password','mydb');
$myArray = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM transcriptome WHERE genename LIKE '%$search_value%'")) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $myArray = $row;
    }
    file_put_contents('jsonoutput.json', json_encode($myArray));
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}

$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

My actual output:
(given a gene (xkr4) as input)

```
{"genename":"xkr4","TA11MEAN":"974.25","TA11STD":"99.0085223605","TA21MEAN":"710.75","TA21STD":"115.79831605","TA22MEAN":"736.5","TA22STD":"115.79831605","TA23MEAN":"903.75","TA23STD":"107.283211641","TB11MEAN":"799.25","TB11STD":"97.2660655111","TB21MEAN":"658","TB21STD":"91.7959694104","TB22MEAN":"592.75","TB22STD":"70.9379129944","TB23MEAN":"864","TB23STD":"92.7280971443"}
```

How I'd like to get my output:

```
{"genename":"xkr4",{"TA11MEAN":"974.25"},{"TA11STD":"99.0085223605"},{"TA21MEAN":"710.75"},{"TA21STD":"115.79831605"},{"TA22MEAN":"736.5"},{"TA22STD":"115.79831605"},{"TA23MEAN":"903.75"},{"TA23STD":"107.283211641"},{"TB11MEAN":"799.25"},{"TB11STD":"97.2660655111"},{"TB21MEAN":"658"},{"TB21STD":"91.7959694104"},{"TB22MEAN":"592.75"},{"TB22STD":"70.9379129944"},{"TB23MEAN":"864"},{"TB23STD":"92.7280971443"}}
```

If someone could give me direction on this (or solve it) That would be great!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `json_encode( $data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT )`

Comment: Are you sure you need this pretty printed? JS, or whatever you're using to decode the json won't care as long as it's valid JSON.

Comment: That doesn't make sense why do care about JSON style or beauty it must be valid.

Comment: You should read the format. The format i want contains {} and is seperated by comma's....I don't care the style either, just to clarify...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to first check how are you getting back your data in array.
$myArray[] should have the data populated as shown below. Then use JSON_PRETTY_PRINT.

```
    /*USED TO SHOW FULL ARRAY SIZE*/
    ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', -1);
    ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_children', -1);
    ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_data', -1);


    $myArray=array("genename"=>array(array("xkr4"=>array(
    array("TA11MEAN"=>"974.25","TA11STD"=>"99.0085223605"),
    array("TA21MEAN"=>"710.75","TA21STD"=>"115.79831605"),
    array("TA22MEAN"=>"736.5","TA22STD"=>"115.79831605"),
    array("TA23MEAN"=>"903.75","TA23STD"=>"107.283211641"),
    array("TB11MEAN"=>"799.25","TB11STD"=>"97.2660655111"),
    array("TB21MEAN"=>"658","TB21STD"=>"91.7959694104"),
    array("TB22MEAN"=>"592.75","TB22STD"=>"70.9379129944"),
    array("TB23MEAN"=>"864","TB23STD"=>"92.7280971443"),

))));
$jsonData=json_encode($myArray,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

var_dump($jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_from_database='[{"genename":"xkr4","TA11MEAN":"974.25","TA11STD":"99.0085223605","TA21MEAN":"710.75","TA21STD":"115.79831605","TA22MEAN":"736.5","TA22STD":"115.79831605","TA23MEAN":"903.75","TA23STD":"107.283211641","TB11MEAN":"799.25","TB11STD":"97.2660655111","TB21MEAN":"658","TB21STD":"91.7959694104","TB22MEAN":"592.75","TB22STD":"70.9379129944","TB23MEAN":"864","TB23STD":"92.7280971443"}]';

//print decode array from databse
$decoded=json_decode($json_from_database);

var_dump($decoded);
foreach ($decoded[0] as $key => $value) {
  echo   "\n  ";
  print $key;
  print "   " .$decoded[0]->$key;
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (17) {
    ["genename"]=>
    string(4) "xkr4"
    ["TA11MEAN"]=>
    string(6) "974.25"
    ["TA11STD"]=>
    string(13) "99.0085223605"
    ["TA21MEAN"]=>
    string(6) "710.75"
    ["TA21STD"]=>
    string(12) "115.79831605"
    ["TA22MEAN"]=>
    string(5) "736.5"
    ["TA22STD"]=>
    string(12) "115.79831605"
    ["TA23MEAN"]=>
    string(6) "903.75"
    ["TA23STD"]=>
    string(13) "107.283211641"
    ["TB11MEAN"]=>
    string(6) "799.25"
    ["TB11STD"]=>
    string(13) "97.2660655111"
    ["TB21MEAN"]=>
    string(3) "658"
    ["TB21STD"]=>
    string(13) "91.7959694104"
    ["TB22MEAN"]=>
    string(6) "592.75"
    ["TB22STD"]=>
    string(13) "70.9379129944"
    ["TB23MEAN"]=>
    string(3) "864"
    ["TB23STD"]=>
    string(13) "92.7280971443"
  }
}

  genename   xkr4
  TA11MEAN   974.25
  TA11STD   99.0085223605
  TA21MEAN   710.75
  TA21STD   115.79831605
  TA22MEAN   736.5
  TA22STD   115.79831605
  TA23MEAN   903.75
  TA23STD   107.283211641
  TB11MEAN   799.25
  TB11STD   97.2660655111
  TB21MEAN   658
  TB21STD   91.7959694104
  TB22MEAN   592.75
  TB22STD   70.9379129944
  TB23MEAN   864
  TB23STD   92.7280971443
This is how your data looks like from database it is a array of rows row is a object
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
<?php

$search_value=$_POST["search"];
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','password','mydb');
$myArray = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM transcriptome WHERE genename LIKE '%$search_value%'")) {


     while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
     $myArray = $row;
     }
     //file_put_contents('jsonoutput.json', json_encode($myArray));
     $json = json_encode($myArray);
     $array = json_decode($json, true);

     $new_array = array();  
     foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
     $newarray[] = array($key=>$value); 
     }

echo json_encode($newarray);
file_put_contents('jsonoutput.json', json_encode($newarray));



}


$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```